# Trouble with NSData and JSON

Tags: json, swift

I have an app that loads JSON from an API over the network. Under usual data sets, it works correctly, and my debug code right before the return will print my JSON contents. However, with one particular data set, the JSON contents are null, and I can't figure out why. Following is the relevant code from my networking class, as well as the data set it's choking on.

```
    // prepare the NSURL and other request parts
    let requestUrl = NSURL(string:escapedUrlString!)
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL: requestUrl!)
    let res:AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?> = nil

    // send the request; get a response
    let responseData = try? NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(req, returningResponse: res) as NSData!

    let finalResponseJSON = JSON(data: responseData!)
    print(finalResponseJSON)
    return finalResponseJSON
```

And the JSON:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "",
  "displayname": "",
  "username": "",
  "avaurl": "",
  "location": "",
  "bio": "",
  "followers": 0,
  "following": 0,
  "blocked": false,
  "statusid": 0,
  "statuses": [
    {
      "id": 2356,
      "username": "grogov",
      "success": true,
      "failmessage": "",
      "author": "grogov",
      "authoravatar": "http://i.imgur.com/0gaAKHB.jpg",
      "content": "'Snowboarding with the NYPD': YouTube filmmakers use NYC blizzard kills 24, Washington struggles to rebound",
      "group": "Public",
      "time": "2016-01-25T00:38:00.053"
    },
    {
      "id": 2355,
      "username": "grogov",
      "success": true,
      "failmessage": "",
      "author": "grogov",
      "authoravatar": "http://i.imgur.com/0gaAKHB.jpg",
      "content": "It’s not just Flint residents still paying bills for viral video",
      "group": "Public",
      "time": "2016-01-24T21:33:50.25"
    },
    {
      "id": 2354,
      "username": "grogov",
      "success": true,
      "failmessage": "",
      "author": "grogov",
      "authoravatar": "http://i.imgur.com/0gaAKHB.jpg",
      "content": "Amid confusion, officials clarify ID 'request' in Flint residents still paying bills for viral video",
      "group": "Public",
      "time": "2016-01-24T21:30:14.237"
    },
    {
      "id": 2353,
      "username": "grogov",
      "success": true,
      "failmessage": "",
      "author": "grogov",
      "authoravatar": "http://i.imgur.com/0gaAKHB.jpg",
      "content": "Flint residents still paying bills for viral video",
      "group": "Public",
      "time": "2016-01-24T21:26:25.47"
    },
    {
      "id": 2352,
      "username": "grogov",
      "success": true,
      "failmessage": "",
      "author": "grogov",
      "authoravatar": "http://i.imgur.com/0gaAKHB.jpg",
      "content": "'Snowboarding with the NYPD': YouTube filmmakers use NYC blizzard shutdown for contaminated water",
      "group": "Public",
      "time": "2016-01-24T21:26:07.97"
    }
  ],
  "users": null,
  "groups": null,
  "trends": null
}
```

Comment: Are you using a library like SwiftyJSON?

Comment: Yep. I am using SwiftyJSON.

Comment: I don't understand where is your issue because your code and JSON worked for me in a sample app ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOydEE8ls4BJjZMUZ55Ip2hvOGJSwz90AII)).